# delete an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to delete a textbox. If I use remove() it is just hiding.If i inspect, it is displaying "display:none" as attribute.

Basically my program is fetching a number from the numberbox n creating those many textboxes. and I am displaying the values of all text boxes.
After entering data into all the textboxes, if I delete one of them n print, i dont want the data of the deleted text box to print. But my code is printing that. Is there any way to remove the textbox completely? remove() is not working as i expected here.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        var id=1,text;
//      text = '<li><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';

        $("#ok").click(function(){
            var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
            //alert(number);
            for(var $j=i; $j<= number; $j++){
                text = '<li><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
                $("ol").append(text);
                id++;i++;
            }

        });

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            text = '<li ><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
            $("ol").append(text);
            id++;i++;
        });

        $('.divi').on('click','.btn2',function(){
          $(this).parents("li").slideUp('medium',function(){
                $(this).parents("li").remove();
                i--;
            });     
        }); 

        $("#btnprint").click(function(){
            var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
            var msg="";
            for(var j=1; j<=number; j++){
                msg+=document.getElementById("input_" +j).value + "<br/>";
            }
            document.getElementById("printdiv").innerHTML=msg;
        });

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="number" id="num" autofocus="true"></input>
    <button id="ok">OK</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <button id="btn1">+</button>

    <div class="divi">
        <ol>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <button id="btnprint" >Print Data</button>
    <div id="printdiv"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `$(this).remove();` cause you're already in the scope of your `LI` element.

Comment: ya I know tat. But here remove() is not completely removing the element. Instead it is removing the element from the view which is same as hiding. I meant the data is still present even after removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    var id = 1,
      text;
    //      text = '<li><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';

    $("#ok").click(function() {
      var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
      //alert(number);
      for (var $j = i; $j <= number; $j++) {
        text = '<li><input id="input_' + id + '" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
        $("ol").append(text);
        id++;
        i++;
      }

    });

    $("#btn1").click(function() {
      text = '<li ><input id="input_' + id + '" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
      $("ol").append(text);
      id++;
      i++;
    });

    $('.divi').on('click', '.btn2', function() {
      $(this).parent().slideUp('medium',function(){
                $(this).remove();
                i--;
            });
    });

     $("#btnprint").click(function() {
  var number = $("#num").val();
  var msg = "";
  for (var j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
    msg += $('ol li').eq(j-1).find('input[id^="input_"]').val() + "<br/>";
  }
  $("#printdiv").html(msg);
});

  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1187/

or

```
  $("#btnprint").click(function() {
      var number = $("#num").val();
      var msg = "";
      $('input[id^="input_"]').each(function(){
        msg += $(this).val() + "<br/>";
      });
      $("#printdiv").html(msg);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxjL4t62/

Comment: Data isn't getting printed

Comment: its not displaying any data. And the error is  "addrow.php:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/sxjL4t62/ if you don't use the counter number in the first input field

Comment: thank you @madalin ivascu its almost done.. but the data undefined is displaying. I'll try solving that. Major part is done. Thanq

Comment: jsfiddle.net/sxjL4t62  is working completely fine thanq

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in this line:

```
$(this).parents("li").remove();
```

The selector is wrong. `$(this)` already refers to `"li"` and on top of that you are selecting `li` parents of `li` which is wrong, hence `remove()` doesn't work. BTW, `display:none` is due to the `slideUp()` function.

Make that line:

```
$(this).remove();
```

**A working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1186/

Comment: `$(this).remove();` doesn't work. It just remove the button.

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman $(this) refers to li inside the slideUp. Scope of $(this) changes inside the function.

Comment: @K K "demo" isn't printing.

Comment: @Poojanagarajrao Demo is just to show you the delete part, I believe this is where you were stuck

Comment: @K K deleting is ok.. but I dont want the data of the deleted element to be printed

Comment: @Poojanagarajrao You also want to remove the printed data when deleting the element?

Comment: Yes, delete is ok. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1188/)

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        var id=1,text;
//      text = '<li><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';

        $("#ok").click(function(){
            var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
            //alert(number);
            for(var $j=i; $j<= number; $j++){
                text = '<li><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
                $("ol").append(text);
                id++;i++;
            }

        });

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            text = '<li ><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
            $("ol").append(text);
            id++;i++;
        });

        $('.divi').on('click', '.btn2', function() {
             $(this).parents("li").slideUp('medium', function() {
             $(this).remove();
             i--;
          });
       });

         $("#btnprint").click(function(){ 
            var number = $(".divi ol li").length;

            var msg="";
            for(var j=1; j<=number; j++){
                msg += document.getElementById("input_" +j).value + "<br/>";
            }
            document.getElementById("printdiv").innerHTML=msg;
        });

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="number" id="num" autofocus="true"></input>
    <button id="ok">OK</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <button id="btn1">+</button>

    <div class="divi">
        <ol>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <button id="btnprint" >Print Data</button>
    <div id="printdiv"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Data isn't getting printed

Comment: Which data is not getting printed ?

Comment: no data is printed.. I want the data of the visible textboxes to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dear now your code is working as per as your requirement.
Please only replace your code with this code.
Written Here....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>         
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var i = 1;
                var id = 1, text;
                //      text = '<li><input id="input_'+id+'" type="text"/>      <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';

                $("#ok").click(function() {
                    var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
                    //alert(number);
                    for (var $j = i; $j <= number; $j++) {
                        text = '<li><input id="input_' + id + '" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
                        $("ol").append(text);
                        id++;
                        i++;
                    }

                });

                $("#btn1").click(function() {
                    text = '<li ><input id="input_' + id + '" type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
                    $("ol").append(text);
                    id++;
                    i++;
                });

                $('.divi').on('click', '.btn2', function() {
                    var tempIndx = $(this).parent().index();
                    $(this).parents("li").slideUp('medium', function() {
                        $('.divi ol').find("li").eq(tempIndx).remove();
                        i--;
                    });
                });

                $("#btnprint").click(function() {
                    var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
                    var msg = "";
                    for (var j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
                        msg += document.getElementById("input_" + j).value + "<br/>";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("printdiv").innerHTML = msg;
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="number" id="num" autofocus="true">
        </input>
        <button id="ok">
            OK
        </button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button id="btn1">
            +
        </button>

        <div class="divi">
            <ol></ol>
        </div>

        <button id="btnprint" >
            Print Data
        </button>
        <div id="printdiv"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: its not displaying any data. And the error is "addrow.php:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: Hi Pooja right now copy and paste your code on my editor then i can do it how can this possible.